# List of available r markdown themes

Tags: r, r-markdown

There are many [markdown themes](http://www.datadreaming.org/post/r-markdown-theme-gallery/) available for R.

I want to view the list of themes available by default and those I have installed. Is there an R command for this?

Comment: Are you sure that StackOverflow is the right place for this question? It seems to be rather related to software usage.

Comment: I agree with your comment but I searched over web for long and couldn't find a solution. So may be it helps others also.

Comment: I agree with Peter. This question definitely is off-topic here.

Comment: I disagree:  it's a programming question ("what code lists all themes?").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In actual fact, there is no such thing as an R Markdown theme.  Various output drivers have themes, but they are not usable in other output drivers.

The `html_document` output driver has 14 themes, which you can list using

```
rmarkdown:::themes()
```

The web page you listed (http://www.datadreaming.org/post/r-markdown-theme-gallery/) talks about themes in other packages, but those packages provide their own output drivers.  For example, `prettydoc` has 5 themes, but they only work with the `prettydoc` output driver, not with `html_document`.